# Count paragraph in file

Tags: c, file

i am working in file system in that i am counting paragraph  from the file but 
i am not getting please suggest me how can i do that i tried this but not getting what i want

```
int main()
    {
            FILE *fp=fopen("200_content.txt ","r");
            int pCount=0;
            char c;
            while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
            {
                    if(c=='\n'){pCount++;}
                    else{continue;} 
            }
            printf("%d",pCount);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is desired output and what are you getting? For starters, no need of `else` clause at all.

Comment: Are paragraph separated by a line with only a newline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph contains two subsequent `'\n'`s, use a variable for counting the two `'\n'`s, like this,

```
int main()
{
        FILE *fp=fopen("200_content.txt ","r");
        int pCount=0;
        char c;
        int newln_cnt=0;
        while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        { 
                if(c=='\n')
                {
                  newln_cnt++;
                  if(newln_cnt==2)
                  {

                     pCount++;
                     newln_cnt=0;
                  }
                }
                else{continue;} 
        }
        printf("%d",pCount);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `c` as `int` instead of `char`.

Also, remember to `fclose(fp);` before `main()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You code counts the number of newline `'\n'` characters, not empty line which demarcates the paragraphs. Use `fgets` to read lines from the file. I suggest this -

```
#include <stdio.h>

// maximum length a line can have in the file. 
// +1 for the terminating null byte added by fgets
#define MAX_LEN 100+1   

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LEN];
    FILE *fp = fopen("200_content.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("error in opening the file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int pcount = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        if(line[0] == '\n') {
            // if newline is found and temp is 1 then
            // this means end of the paragraph. increase
            // the paragraph counter pcount and set temp to 0
            if(temp == 1)
                pcount++;

            temp = 0;
        }
        else {
            // if a non-empty line is found, this means
            // the start of the paragraph
            temp = 1;
        }
    }

    // if the last para doesn't end with empty line(s)
    if(temp == 1)
        pcount++;

    printf("number of para in the file is %d\n", pcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I assume that you consider a new line to be a new paragraph.
i.e.

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
```

has 2 paragraphs.

What your code does is neglect the case where there is an EOF and not a newline character (\n) after `This is line 2.`

One way to fix this is to use an extra `char` variable.

```
int main()
{
        FILE *fp=fopen("200_content.txt ","r");
        int pCount=0;
        char c; // char that checks
        char last_c; //record of the last character read in the loop
        while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
                if(c=='\n'){pCount++;}
                last_c = c;
                else{continue;} //this line is redundant. You can remove it 
        }
        if (last_c != '\n') pCount++; //if EOF at the end of line and not '\n'

        printf("%d",pCount);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void analyze_file(const char *filename) {
    FILE* out_file;
    out_file = fopen(filename,"r");
    int size;
    if(out_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error(analyze_file): Could not open file %s\n",filename);
        return;
    }
    
    fseek(out_file,0,SEEK_SET);
    char ch,ch1;
    int alpha_count = 0,num_count = 0,non_alnum =0,charac=0;
    int word_count =0,line=0;
    int para=0;

    while(!feof(out_file))
    {
        ch = fgetc(out_file);

        if (isalpha(ch))
            alpha_count++;

        else if(isdigit(ch))
            num_count++;

        else if(!isalnum(ch) && ch!='\n'  && !isspace(ch))
            ++non_alnum;

        else if(ch=='\n')
        {   line++;
        ch1 = fgetc(out_file);// courser moves ahead , as we read
        fseek(out_file,-1,SEEK_CUR); // bringing courser back

        }

        else if(ch == ch1)
            {para++; //paragraph counter
            word_count--;
            }


        if(ch==' '||ch=='\n')
                            {
                                word_count++;
                            }
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            word_count++;line++;para++;
        }
    }
    non_alnum -=1;// EOF character subtracted.
    charac = alpha_count + non_alnum + num_count;
    fclose(out_file);

    

    printf("#Paragraphs = %d\n",para);
    printf("#lines = %d\n",line);
    printf("#Words = %d\n",word_count);
    printf("#Characters = %d\n",charac);
    printf("Alpha = %d\n",alpha_count);
    printf("Numerical = %d\n",num_count);
    printf("Other = %d\n",non_alnum);
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```